# How to promote my own apps with AdMob after August 2016

Tags: google, advertising

I use AdMob to **promote my apps.**

Right now, in AdMob management board I have a *Promote* tab and it is way too easy to add a new ad by specifying an *ad image of my own app* and that ad will be advertised in Google's network.

Plain and simple.

[image]

However, I got a notification about the retiring of the *Promote* tab and its replacement will be the *Campaigns*.

I still intend to promote my own apps so I checked what to do.

I got confused as the Campaigns seem to be consisting only of ***lending my ad units.***

I can set goals (click or percentage - I don't even understand how a percentage could help me promoting my apps...) and specify my ad units in my apps. What if I don't have an app with an ad unit? Then I can't create a campaign?

It seem, I can't continue unless I select one of my ad-containing app.
Why?

[image]

[image]

Why did they take away the promotion? What should I do about this? Should I select my other apps?

Answer (score 1):

[Google now suggests using Adwords for paid campaigns](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7028917?hl=en-GB)

> Paid ad campaign creation has been removed from AdMob. We suggest using AdWords, Google's online advertising programme, to create new paid ad campaigns.